# Redmine agile_rank no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, redmine

My versions :

- Redmine: 2.5.2
- Ruby: 2.1.5p273
- Rails: 4.2.5

My Environement variables :

```
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
PATH = /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD = /usr/share/redmine
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
LANG = C   
SHLVL = 1
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2   
_ = /usr/sbin/apache2
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXCWhgdC
USER = www-data
LOGNAME = www-data
SHELL = /usr/sbin/nologin
HOME = /var/www
IN_PASSENGER = 1
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
RAILS_ENV = production
RACK_ENV = production
WSGI_ENV = production
NODE_ENV = production
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production  
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) 
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/html/redmine
SERVER_ADMIN = [no address given]
QUERY_STRING =
SERVER_NAME = meetursam.fr
REMOTE_PORT = 41199
REMOTE_ADDR = 37.58.159.61
SERVER_PORT = 3000
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
SERVER_ADDR = 91.121.89.137
REQUEST_URI = /
GEM_PATH = /var/lib/gems/2.1.0:/var/www/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
GEM_HOME = /var/lib/gems/2.1.0
X_DEBIAN_SITEID = default
RAILS_ETC = /etc/redmine/default
BUNDLE_BIN_PATH = /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-1.7.4/bin/bundle
BUNDLE_GEMFILE = /usr/share/redmine/Gemfile
RUBYOPT = -rbundler/setup
RUBYLIB = /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
RAILS_LOG = /var/log/redmine/default
RAILS_VAR = /var/lib/redmine/default
RAILS_TMP = /var/cache/redmine/default
```

I have a problem when I use the rake command:

```
root@meetursam:/usr/share/redmine# rake --trace

Invoke default (first_time)
Invoke test (first_time)
Execute test
Invoke test:run (first_time)
Invoke test:units (first_time)
Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
Execute test:prepare
Execute test:units
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'test' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:224:in `resolve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:152:in `resolve'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:182:in `spec'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.14/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/test/test_helper.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/test/unit/activity_test.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run => test:units
```

I do not have database.yml file, I tried to create it but the problem is the same.
I did that in config/database.yml

```
production:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: localhost
    username: redmine
    password: redmine
    encoding: utf8
test:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: localhost
    username: redmine
    password: redmine
    encoding: utf8
```

I don't have any log in /var/log/redmine/* (files are empty)

When I go on my webserver I get this error by passenger:

```
No such file to load -- agile_rank (LoadError)
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
  /usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/redmine_agile/lib/redmine_agile/patches/issue_patch.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/redmine_agile/lib/redmine_agile.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/redmine_agile/init.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `instance_exec'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `block in make_lambda'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:187:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:187:in `block in simple'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `block in call'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `each'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
  /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What Redmine plugins do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like plugins compatibility issue. Try to move all plugins from redmine/plugins folder except redmine_agile and then add one by one to localize conflicted one.